# How to intercept Chrome links with Advanced Download Manager (ADM)?

Tags: chrome-for-android, download-manager

I have installed [Advanced Download Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dv.adm) (ADM), but when I try downloading a file from Chrome, it downloads the file with its Chrome download manager.

How to set-up ADM to intercept the download link on Chrome?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the recommendations made in [other answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/203520/218526), do note a few things:

- ADM can intercept downloads from within its own browser, not from other apps, except from those which are looking for a browser/downloader app.
- Apps which depend on Android's [activity resolver](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters#Resolution) (to show chooser dialog or *"Complete action using"* by sending an [implicit intent](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters#Types)) can forward downloadable links to ADM (and other apps which register [preferred activities](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getPreferredActivities(java.util.List%3Candroid.content.IntentFilter%3E,%20java.util.List%3Candroid.content.ComponentName%3E,%20java.lang.String)) as downloaders).

  Apps can also [query](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryIntentActivities(android.content.Intent,%20int)) available activities for a certain intent (action, path and/or mime) type and then send explicit intent to an app chosen by user. E.g. Firefox looks for system's preferred activities for a given URL and mime type and maintains its own download preferences for all mime types.

  ADM - in its `AndroidManifest.xml` file - registers itself for `android.intent.action.VIEW`, category `DEFAULT`/`BROWSABLE`, scheme `http`/`https`, all mime types and a long list of file extensions. So do other apps like MiXplorer and Firefox itself. Therefore they appears as eligible candidates when (an app through) OS looks for a downloader/browser.
- Xposed module "Download Redirection" can intercept all downloads which are forwarded by apps to Android's Download Manager (`com.android.providers.downloads`).
- But for apps which use their internal downloader, links need to be shared to ADM or copied to clipboard so that ADM can intercept them.

---

**RELATED:**

- [Alternative “File Open” - how ”ResolverActivity” works?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/210168/218526)

Comment: Actually, this isn't completely accurate; ADM *can* intercept links from other browsers, it's just that Chrome is not one of the compatible browsers.  The ADM telegram group has a robot command you can use to check the list of compatible and incompatible browsers.

Comment: @Arctiic "*ADM can intercept links from other browsers*". True. That's what's explained in the second point. // "*Chrome is not one of the compatible browsers*". True. That's what's explained in the last point.

Comment: Yes, I understand, I was specifically referring to the first bullet: "ADM can intercept downloads from *within its own browser, not from other apps*."  Maybe you didn't intend it as such, but that reads to me as an attribution of exclusivity.

Comment: @Arctiic you are correct. I changed the first bullet to make more sense.

Answer (score 2):

Normally ADM should be able to intercept downloads automatically provided its service is running in the background.

- You can check if the setting is active here: ADM Settings → Automation → Autostart service (**tick box**).
- Secondly make sure it is activated for both mobile and wi-fi networks ADM Settings → Automation → Only via wi-fi (**untick**)
- Also here, you need to fine tune the settings for download interception such as enabling the option when battery is low, and excluded the app from battery optimisation.

Answer (score 2):

Share download links to ADM and it will start download in ADM. You can do so by long pressing on download button and selecting share link option.