# Facebook app appears twice in "Open With"

Tags: facebook, bugs, facebook-messenger

I was trying to open a link to a Facebook post sent in Facebook Messenger recently, and I got an unexpected "Open With" dialog, asking whether I wanted to open it with...

- Facebook

  `com.facebook.katana`
- Facebook

  `com.facebook.katana`

The exact same app entry repeated two times, like so:

[image: Screenshot of the Open With dialog described above]

This looked suspicious to me. Is this possibly a sign of some malware that's masquerading as Facebook on my phone? Or is it just an innocent bug/confusion within the Facebook app or Android system?

Are there particular steps I should take to fix it?

Facebook appears only once in my "App info -> All apps" list.

I'm running Android version 9 on a Google Pixel 2. My Facebook app is version 232.0.0.35.115 - I'm happy to dig up any other diagnostic information that might be useful, just please let me know in a comment what needs to be added/clarified.

Comment: That's because Facebook app registers itself for different intent types that it can handle. When opening the link (you tapped), two of intent types are matched by Android's activity resolver, so the app appears twice. A little more detail here: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218441/218526

Comment: @IrfanLatif Thanks for the info! Post that as an Answer and I'll happily accept & upvote it. :)