# Open links to particular domain with particular app

Tags: default-applications

I use a browser as my default, but wish that links to certain domains be opened *by default* with another browser. For example if an app has a button that opens a website it normally opens it in the default browser. For most situations this is fine, but there a few exceptions I would like to change the browser the site opens in.

Is it possible to set "rules" for default app per domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking this is not an answer but a good workaround. My take on the issue is NOT to set a default browser in Settings. Whenever I click on a link I get the pop-up asking me to choose the browser/app to use. Like that, I can choose to open the links with the browser more appropriate for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK stock Android itself doesn't have any such feature. But it totally depends on the app you are using to open other links. Apps can open certain links with other apps/browsers. For instance browsers (like Firefox) can open `facebook` and `youtube` links in their respective apps if installed. Also it depends on the app which you want to open for a certain domain (if it accepts URL forwarded by other apps). It depends on [intent-filters](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters#Receiving) an app declares in its `AndroidManifest.xml` file. For little more details on this see [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218441/218526).