# Disabling custom tabs, or a browser without custom tabs support?

Tags: applications, browser

I have searched this topic for a while, but the answers I found are sadly outdated. Chrome/Chromium based browsers (I tried Brave and DuckDuckGo, and according to search results Vivaldi also has it) and Firefox has a feature that clicking a link in apps, opens a (very limited) browser inside the app, and not the "normal" browser. As far as I know this is called "Custom tabs".

This feature is annoying, mainly, because a ton of apps does not allow to disable this in itself.

There was a flag in Chrome ( chrome://flags/#tab-management-experiment-type, Switch preferred flavor of Herb ), but they removed it. I don't see any option in Brave, DuckDuckGo and Vivaldi. Firefox also removed the option ( see here, second picture of the answer: [How to open links directly in Firefox full browser?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/219747/how-to-open-links-directly-in-firefox-full-browser)).

Are there any workarounds, hidden options I did not find?