# ADM (Advanced Download Manager) is not grabbing links automatically

Tags: downloading, download-manager

In my previous Android phone, when I to copied any link, there was a popup window of ADM asking whether I wanted to download the specific file or not. It required that ADM should be running in the background.

But now, there's no such pop-up. I've to manually paste links. Although I've enabled the pop-up permission of the app in phone settings.

Is there some other android permission, or ADM setting that I'm missing?

EDIT : I've also checked for auto intercept links, I've enabled it. Still not working.

Comment: [How to intercept Chrome links with Advanced Download Manager (ADM)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218441/218526)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this feature of ADM before, but what you're describing reminded me of a change Android 10 has for security reasons.

In Android 10 apps that are not in focus cannot access your clipboard, not even Google's own Translate app.

Source: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#clipboard-data

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:
Choose ADM as your default browser.
When open a link, the ADM editor will open.