# How to change download manager

Tags: downloading, default-applications

Everytime i try to download anything it uses the built in android download manager.There is no download manager option at default apps . Is there anyway to force the use of my download manager?
My device is Realme 7 and it runs android 10
My download manager is advanced download manager

Comment: When you mention "download anything", what app are you using to invoke the download action, a browser or specialized app? Possibly similar to [How to intercept Chrome links with Advanced Download Manager?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/203348/3573)